# Using Runge Kutta 2 on a System of Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, vectors

So I created a MatLab code to solve an ODE equation, however I'm having a hard time vectorizing everything!

Here is the code as I have it:

```
% Midpoint Rule = Runge Kutta 2

clear

y(1) = 2;
tmax = 30;
h = 0.01;
nstep = tmax/h;
t = 0:h:tmax;

% rk2 loop

for n = 1:nstep
    k1 = h*fxn(t(n),y(n));
    k2 = h*fxn(t(n)+h/2,y(n)+k1/2);
    y(n+1) = y(n)+k2;
end

% output

plot(t,y,'b')
legend('y: rk2')
```

And my current function is:

```
function [dydt] = fxn(t,y)

    dydt = 0.5*y*(1-y/100);

end
```

I want my new functions (a system of ODEs) to look like this:

```
function [dydt] = fxn(t,y)

    y1 = y(1);
    y2 = y(2);

    dydt = [y2;-0.5*y1+2.5*y2];

end
```

I'm not sure how to change the initial conditions vector or the K1, k2, y(n+1) equations to reflect the vector change! Any hints/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I have not checked you have implemented the RK2 algorithm correctly. I have just modified the code that you have provided.

You don't need to change very much at all.

You should preallocate (which is good practice) `y = zeros(2,nstep+1);`, where column `n` of `y` is the solution at time `n-1`.

You need to set the initial condition:

```
y(:,1) = [value1;value2];
```

Your expression for `k1` needs to change so that the vector of current `y` values is passed to `f`:

```
k1 = h * fxn(t(n), y(:,n));
```

Your expression for `k2` needs to change similarly:

```
k2 = h * fxn(t(n) + h/2, y(:,n) + k1/2);
```

And you need to update when you store the solution

```
y(:,n+1) = y(:,n) + k2;
```

This will store the solution for `y1` in the first row of `y` and `y2` in the second row.

As you store the solution for each timestep as a column vector, you need to ensure that your function `fxn` returns a column vector.